# Filter out second set of digits with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

In my HTML markup, there will be a series of elements with the following naming scheme:

```
name="[].timeEntries[].Time"
```

Between both sets of brackets, there will be numbers with at least one possibly two digits. I need to filter out the second set of digits.

Disclaimer: This is my first time getting to know regex.

This is my pattern so far:

```
var re = /\[\d{1,2}\].timeEntries\[(\d{1,2})\]\.Time/;
```

1. I am not sure if I should use the * or + character to indicate two possible digits.
2. Is replace() the right method for this?
3. Do I need to escape the period '.' ?
4. Any other tips you can offer are appreciated.

For example, if I come across an element with

```
name="[10].timeEntries[9].Time"
```

I would like to put just the 9 into a variable.

Comment: * is zero or more, + is one or more

Comment: So are you looking for a replace function? If so, please post expected  output example too

Comment: you can use the positive lookahead assertion. Read http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: `.` matches anything, so be sure to escape it with a `\\`

Comment: `{m,n}` matches the pattern a minimum of `m` times, and a maximum of `n` times (`n` can be omitted)

Comment: In the unlikely event that there was 3 digits? Would you still want to know them all? For example, `123`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am not sure if I should use the * or + character to indicate two possible digits.

Neither, use `{1,2}`

```
\[\d{1,2}\]\.timeEntries\[(\d{1,2})\]\.Time
```

[Example](http://rubular.com/r/3FxAVt2tsZ)

This indicates explicitly 1 or 2 digits.

Also, yes, you should escape the `.`'s

You can use it like this:

```
var re = /\[\d{1,2}\]\.timeEntries\[(\d{1,2})\]\.Time/;

var myNumber = "[0].timeEntries[47].Time".match(re)[1];
```

Now `myNumber` will contain `47`.

One final word of warning, `myNumber` contains the `string` "47". If your intention is to use it as a number you'll need to either use `parseInt` or use `+`:

```
var myNumber = +"[0].timeEntries[47].Time".match(re)[1];
```

Comment: I am sure `\d+` would have been fine

Comment: @musefan: `\d+` would match any number of digits above 1. The requirement was *1 or 2*.

Comment: I know what `\d+` would match, but while the OP's expectation might be 1 or 2, the reality probably is if there was 3 or more, I bet he would want all the digits

Comment: @musefan: If you want to just make up requirements rather than follow what the OP asked for then, yeah, knock yourself out. If there are three or more digits, then the string is malformed according to the OP.

Comment: Sometimes you have to read between the lines. It is clear the number represents an index for an array, should the `timeEntries` array have more than 100 items in (for whatever reason) then the code will suddenly develop a problem. Besides there was no mention of requierments, only what the OP expects the input is likely to be

Comment: @musefan: And sometimes you need to answer the question as it was asked and not make your own, possibly flawed, assumptions.

Comment: @musefan: That's absolutely untrue. The OP edited their question to include my regex **after** I posted it. Check the edit history before you start casting personal attacks around.

Comment: I don't make personal attacks, my comments are just debating my opinions. I would never aim insults (or attacks) at people I don't know. Also, my mistake about the regex in the question, you are correct

Comment: @musefan: You said I didn't answer the question (I did) and you said I didn't understand the question (I did). That's a pretty balsy thing to say to somebody you don't know.

Comment: you are the one that decides what you take offense to, regardless of what my intentions where. Though I assure you I was just debating my point, we cannot all have the same opinions all the time. My overall point however is that it should be made very clear that if the number does grow to 3 or more digits then the code will not behave as expected, the OP is clearly new to this and likely will not understand the problems that may occur

Comment: @musefan: I don't want to keep this going (if you delete some of you more contentious posts, I will delete my responses since they are of no interest to anybody), but your original comment was misleading. You said `\d+` would have "been fine", but it is not. It matches what the OP wanted, plus stuff the OP may or may not have wanted. You did not explain that in your comment at all. Matching stuff you don't expect is *not* fine and you should have added that caveat from the start.

Comment: I think these comments are important. When the time comes where I rule one half of the world, and you rule the other half. People will need this artifact as proof to why it all began. Ultimately though I will win the war, as my army could potentially grow into the hundreds, where yours will be stuck in double figures!

Comment: @musefan: Fair enough...I'll give you that one!

Comment: Actually, it's a time management app. The variable in question will never reference a number higher than about 20, since it is a semi-monthly pay period. It definitely wouldn't go above 99. I appreciate the specificity of this post.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close.

There are a lot of ways you could do this - especially depending on how solid the format of that text will be.

You could use replace:

```
var re = /\[\d+\]\.timeEntries\[([\d]+)\]\.Time/;
var digits = element_name.replace(re, '$1');
```

If you know it will always be the second set of digits, you could use `match`

You could also use `indexOf` and/or `split` and some other string functions...  In some cases that can be faster (but I think in your case, the regex is fine and probably easier to follow)